# servlet returning blank page

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

i m trying to create a registration page in servlet..using tomcat 7 with eclipse, it returning blank page, i have tried available steps but no go.. please help....

**here is JSP page**

```
<form method="post" action="mbregistrationservlet">
First Name: <input type=text name=firstfame><br>
Last Name: <input type=text name=lastname></br>
Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" Value="Male" checked>Male
<input type="radio" name="Gender" Value="Female">Female</br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
Security Question<select name="securityquestion">
                <option value="Name of your first pet">Name of your first pet</option>
                <option value="Name of your first byke">Name of your first byke</option>
                <option value="Name of your first car">Name of your first car</option>
                <option value="Name of your first school">Name of your first school</option>
                <option value="Name of your first GF/BF">Name of your first GF/BF</option>
            </select><br>
Answer: <input type="text" name="answer"><br>
Telephone:<input type="text" name="telephone"><br>
Address:<input type="text" name="address"><br>
City:<input type="text" name="city"><br>
State:<input type="text" name="state"><br>
Country:<input type="text" name="country"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="suuubmit" name="Submit"> 
</form>
```

**Servlet page**

```
public class mbregistrationservlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static boolean register(String firstname, String lastname, String gender,String email, String password, String securityquestion, String answer, String telephone, String address, String city, String state, String country) throws IOException
{
HttpServletResponse response = null;
    //response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    boolean x =false;
    try{
        /*dbconn obj=new dbconn();*/
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","******","*******");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into mbregistration  values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,firstname);
        ps.setString(2,lastname);
        ps.setString(3,gender);
        ps.setString(4, email);
        ps.setString(5, password);
        ps.setString(6, securityquestion);
        ps.setString(7, answer);
        ps.setString(8, telephone);
        ps.setString(9, address);
        ps.setString(10,city);
        ps.setString(11,state);
        ps.setString(12,country);
       int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (i>0){
            x=true;
        }
        out.print("registered succcessfully");
        //out.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        out.print("error");
        //out.close();
    }
    return x;
}
```

**XML page**

```
<display-name>MobileWorld</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>mbloginservlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>mbloginservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>mbworld.mbloginservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mbloginservlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/mbloginservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>Validate</display-name>
<servlet-name>Validate</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>mbworld.Validate</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Validate</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Validate</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>success</display-name>
<servlet-name>success</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>mbworld.success</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>success</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/success</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>mbregistrationservlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>mbregistrationservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>mbworld.mbregistrationservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mbregistrationservlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/mbregistrationservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

please let me know if i m doing something wrong.......

Comment: I don't see doPost() method in servlet, which is actually going to be called by the service when you submit the form

Comment: Accept the best answers for your question, if they helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to write your code in doPost method and the second thing is that if you are not using `rd.forward(request,response)`  after `RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Name of page you want to redirect");` it will be a blank page after you click submit button.

so it should be like:

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your method name as doPost instead of register (without static keyword) and from there using http servlet request access form fields using getParameter api. so it looks like:

```
 public class mbregistrationservlet extends HttpServlet {
      public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String firstName = request.getParameter("firstfame");

     //and so on
 }
```

Comment: thankyou so much for quick reply, i tried code in doPost method with some changes and it worked... thanks again..

Comment: You are welcome. That's why you have forum SO for. Please dont foget to close this question by accepting the answer so that it would be helpful to others in future.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a doPost() method in the servlet, which is actually going to be called by the service method when you submit your form.

**structure of doPost() method**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
// Servlet code
}
```

**Corrections**

1. You are not going to get input fields via parameters as you are expecting with you `register method`

   ```
   public static boolean register(...)
   ```

   morever this is illegal.
2. In,Order to get your input field parameters  user `Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames()` which will return an Enumeration of all the parameters and via `request.getParameterValue(params.nextElement())` you can access value corresponding to the input field specified by `params.nextElement()`.
   [EXAMPLE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm).

Comment: thankyou so much for quick reply, i tried code in doPost method with some changes and it worked... also thank you for providing link of examples..that is really helpful...